# Can I create a json string from wordpress to use it in my mobile app?

Tags: php, android, json, wordpress

Hello I am an android deveeloper but I am very new in web developing. My friend has a wordpress website. I want to create an android app to get data from wordpress website.
How can we create a json string (for all post and data) in wordpress side and parse it in android application??

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the  new WP REST Api so you can pull specific data to your app from Wordpress website.

http://v2.wp-api.org/